# Appending a url using a bookmarklet and clipboard item

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarklet, clipboarddata

I want to append text that has been copied to the clipboard to the end of a url when a bookmarklet is used.

i.e. highlight text, copy and click the bookmarklet and I go to a url with the copied text at the end.

Any help would be great.

I have this code but it works with highlighting text on a browser page. I want to read from the clipboard.

```
javascript:window.location.href="http://www.mybaseurl.com/"+window.getSelection()
```

I also have this code that is a little closer to what I need.

It prompts for input and goes to a url with the input at the end of a url

```
javascript:(function(){var val= prompt("Enter #","");if (val)location="https://www.test.com/send?phone="+escape(val);})()
```

Answer (score 0):

after a bit of fooling around this is what worked for me, do note however that it will be asking for clipboard permissions, so it's somewhat limited in that regard.

javascript:navigator.clipboard.readText().then((clipText) => location="http://www.mybaseurl.com/"+escape(clipText))